# PostgreSQL for multiple users

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql

I am building an app for a workshop at a conference. It will be used by the participants to input answers to a survey on their mobile devices and then these answers will be saved to a database.

I am currently looking at PostgreSQL and from what I have seen it is extremely capable of handling well over 100 expected users that I will have using the app at one time. What I haven't been able to decide conclusively is whether these 100 people all adding to the same database at once will cause any problems. I have looked into locks and understand that theres shouldn't be any conflicts when inserting into tables (which is all the users will be doing) but I just wanted to confirm before moving forward with the app.

I assume it is also important to deploy the app using a hosting service which can handle the load. I am intending to use Heroku which I have experience deploying postgreSQL databases to.

Just in case it is relevant I was intending to use Knex.js to build the database in a node backend.

Happy to provide any further information and would appreciate any input or better suggestions to look into.

Cheers, 
Tim

Comment: PostgreSQL shouldn't have any trouble for 100 simultaneous users inserting rows. Unless each one is inserting massive (> 100k rows each?) number of rows.

Comment: have googled "stress test postgres"?

Comment: @TheImpaler Thanks for that, no no they are literally just answers to some very short questions. And no I haven't Red Cricket, didn't know how to phrase it, will do so now. Cheers!

Comment: App connecting direct  to postgres, or to a web service?

Comment: @Jasen If i understand your question correctly, it is directly connected. Im building the database and the app and deploying together?

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a stupid suggestion, but if all you need is for participants to input answers to a survey, and have their answers stored in a database, why not just use Google Forms? That way your survey data would get stored in a Google Sheet, with 0 coding required from your end. If you then need to export that info to a DB, there are lots of solutions for that, e.g. https://zapier.com/apps/google-sheets/integrations/postgresql.

Comment: @YoniRabinovitch Unfortunately I need to be giving live data analysis during the workshop. So all the information needs to be fed straight into graphing algorithms etc.

Comment: @TimTolley: Even more of a reason to use Google Forms, IMHO. All of your response data would be immediately available in a Google Sheet, where it could be easily and automatically transformed into auto-updating, online visualisations.  See e.g. https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/turn-your-google-docs-form-responses-into-beautiful-visualizations--cms-21520. Another option that you might want to check is Survey Monkey (https://www.surveymonkey.com). Based on the info you provided, it doesn't sound like you really need to build your own system for this. Good luck!